# Object detection model training get stuck without any error message

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am training a object detection model on google colab.
After executing the below command the output get freeze for almost an hour and then execution get terminated without any error message.

command:

```
!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=/content/drive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/workspace/training_demo/models/my_ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=/content/drive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/workspace/training_demo/models/my_ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn/pipeline.config
```

Output:

**W0918 08:59:41.794937 140133310125952 deprecation.py:356] From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1082: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.**

I am referring [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#) article for object detection.

Please help me to solve this issue.